# Gravar apenas relacionamento entre Objetos - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Utilizando a plataforma .Net com o Entity Framework.

Estou persistindo um objeto da classe A_B  que se relaciona com A e B conforme código abaixo:

```
public class A_B
{
    private int Id;
    private string name;

    private A a;
    private B b;
}

public class A
{
    private int Id;
    private string name;
}

public class B
{
    private int Id;
    private string name;
}
```

O problema é que toda vez que vou incluir A_B, automaticamente, o Entity Framework inclui B e A, mas não quero incluir B e A, pois já existem no banco de dados. Estou incluindo apenas o relacionamento entre esses objetos.

Para salvar eu uso somente estas linhas:

```
context.Entry(A_B).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

ou

```
context.Entry(A_B).State = EntityState.Added;

DbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: votar contra
 

O specificationToSave seria o objeto do carro também?

Se sim, teria que pegar os códigos das rodas que estão no carro, e setar no objecto specificationToSave.

Tem como passar mais detalhes como quais parametros dos objetos, talvez um diagrama ER para que possamos lhe ajudar?

Comment: Segue as classes

   public class A_B
    {
        private int Id;
        private string name;

        private A a;
        private B b;
    }

    public class A
    {
        private int Id;
        private string name;
    }

    public class B
    {
        private int Id;
        private string name;
    }

Comment: Não é duplicata. Vou responder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua modelagem está errada. Veja as correções abaixo:

```
public class A_B
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }; // Use propriedade, não campo.
    [Index("IUQ_AB_AId_BId", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int AId { get; set; }; // Adicione.
    [Index("IUQ_AB_AId_BId", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public int BId { get; set; }; // Adicione.

    public string name { get; set; }; // Use propriedade, não campo.

    public virtual A a { get; set; }; // Use propriedade, não campo.
    public B b { get; set; }; // Use propriedade, não campo.
}

public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }; // Use propriedade, não campo.
    public string name { get; set; }; // Use propriedade, não campo.
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }; // Use propriedade, não campo.
    public string name { get; set; }; // Use propriedade, não campo.
}
```

Ao montar o objeto, duas opções:

#### 1. Selecionar as entidades associativas e atribuir como propriedades de navegação

```
var a = context.As.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == idDeA);
var b = context.Bs.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == idDeB);
var a_b = new A_B { a, b };
context.As_Bs.Add(a_b);
context.SaveChanges();
```

#### 2. Atribuir Ids em tela e salvar objeto

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    context.As_Bs.Add(a_b);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Como não existe edição de entidade associativa, não faz sentido usar `context.Entry(A_B).State = EntityState.Modified;`.

Comment: Cigano, por que não usar campo?

Comment: Porque eles não podem ser marcados como `virtual`. Suponha que você use herança. Algo como `public class C : A { ... }`, só que você precisa acrescentar comportamentos em alguma das propriedades. Como campo, isso é impossível.

Answer (score 0):

Brother, você vai ter que recuperar do banco o objeto A ou B e deixa-lo com track no contexto e adicionar o objeto A_B ao objeto recuperado, assim o entity vai entender que o objeto recuperado já existe e sabe que deverá inserir em sua associativa.

Se você tiver uma tabela de muitos para muitos das classes A e B, também pode recuperar um dos dois objetos do banco (deixando o track no contexto) e adicionando o outro no objeto recuperado, por exemplo:

```
public void Teste()
    {
        var objA = _contexto.A.FisrtOrDefault(a => a.Id.Equals(a.Id));

        if(objA != null)
        {
            objA.ListaDeB.Add(objB);
            _contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```